# Rewrite query to not use CONCAT function in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I know that the CONCAT function does not exist in SQL Server prior to [2012](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). How would i optimize my code to not use the CONCAT function?

```
         SELECT  dbname = DB_NAME(),
                  file_name = name, 
                  TotalMB = CONVERT(decimal(12,1),size/128.0),
                  UsedMB = CONVERT(decimal(12,1),FILEPROPERTY(name,'SpaceUsed')/128.0),
                  FreeMB = CONVERT(decimal(12,1),(size - FILEPROPERTY(name,'SpaceUsed'))/128.0),
                  Command = CONCAT('USE MASTER; ALTER DATABASE ', DB_NAME(), '; MODIFY FILE (name = ',
                        [name], ', size = ', 
                        convert(int,round(1.15 * FILEPROPERTY(name,'SpaceUsed')/128,-1)), 'MB)')
           FROM sys.database_files WITH (NOLOCK)
           WHERE type_desc = 'ROWS'
           ORDER BY file_id;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can concatenate strings in SQL Server just by using the `+` operator. So to avoid using `CONCAT`, your code can be rewritten as:

```
SELECT  dbname = DB_NAME(),
                 file_name = name, 
                 TotalMB = CONVERT(decimal(12,1),size/128.0),
                 UsedMB = CONVERT(decimal(12,1),FILEPROPERTY(name,'SpaceUsed')/128.0),
                 FreeMB = CONVERT(decimal(12,1),(size - FILEPROPERTY(name,'SpaceUsed'))/128.0),
                 Command = 'USE MASTER; ALTER DATABASE ' + DB_NAME() + '; MODIFY FILE (name = ' + 
                    [name] + ', size = ' + convert(int,round(1.15 * FILEPROPERTY(name,'SpaceUsed')/128,-1)) + 'MB)'
FROM sys.database_files WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE type_desc = 'ROWS'
ORDER BY file_id;
```

Comment: Just a couple of comments, FYI. I don't think you have to worry about them for this script, but can be good to know for other situations: Two things that CONCAT does for you is 1) it replaced NULL with an empty string (so that whole result doesn't become NULL) and 2) it converts to string (so for exampe an INT doesn't result in the strings being coverted to INT due to data type precedence).